# which part is wrong with my RNN bptt paritial deritaives?

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

## forward

use cross entroy as loss.

$$
s_t = tanh(Ux_t+Ws_{t-1}) \\
o_t = softmax(Vs_t) \\
L(y,o) = - \sum_t y_t log(o_t) = - \sum_t L_t
$$

## backpropagation

firtly,

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial V} = \sum_{t}\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial V} = \sum_{t}(y_t - o_t)s_t 
$$

suppose:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial U} &= \sum_{t}\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial U} \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W} &= \sum_{t}\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial W} \\
\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial s_t} &= \alpha_t =  (y_t-o_t)V  \\
\end{align}
$$

$$z_t = Ux_t + Ws_{t-1}$$.So,$$\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial z_t} = \beta_t= 1-tanh^2(z_t)$$。

then for W,

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial z_t}{\partial W} &= \sigma_t =  W\frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W} \\
\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial W} &= \frac{\partial L_t}{\partial s_t}\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} \\
&= \frac{\partial L_t}{\partial s_t}\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial z_t}\frac{\partial z_t}{\partial W} \\
&=\alpha_t \beta_t ( W\frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W}) \\
&=\alpha_t \beta_t ( W^2\frac{\partial s_{t-2}}{\partial W}) \\
\end{align}
$$

which confused me is that,my deritaive seems different with this [blog](http://www.wildml.com/2015/10/recurrent-neural-networks-tutorial-part-3-backpropagation-through-time-and-vanishing-gradients/)
and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backpropagation_through_time)

[image: sum s gradient]

they all sum the $s_t$ gradient.

Please help to figure it out.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the missed part is how to calculate the  derivative of $\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial W}$,

\begin{align}
q_t &= Vs_t\\\\
\frac{\partial L_t}{\partial W} &= \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_t}\frac{\partial q_t}{\partial s_t}
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W}
\\
&= (y- o_t)V \frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W}\\
\end{align} 
casuse:
$$s_t = tanh(Ux_t + Ws_{t-1})$$
here $s_{t-1}$is also a function of $W$,so the correct partial derivative rule is
$$
\frac{\partial f(x)g(x)}{\partial x} = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)
$$

then we get the final formula from the steps below:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} &= \frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} 
+ \frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}}\frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W} \\
&=\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} 
+ \frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}}(\frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W}) \\
&=\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} +   
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}} 
  ( \frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W}
    + \frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial s_{t-2}} \frac{\partial s_{t-2}}{\partial W}
    ) \\
&=\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} + 
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}}    \frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W} +
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}}     
  \frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial s_{t-2}} \frac{\partial s_{t-2}}{\partial W} \\
&=\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial W} + 
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-1}}    \frac{\partial s_{t-1}}{\partial W} +
\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_{t-2}}  \frac{\partial s_{t-2}}{\partial W} \\
&=\sum^t_{r=0}\frac{\partial s_t}{\partial s_r}\frac{\partial s_r}{\partial W}
\end{align}
$$

That's it.Hope it may help others who have the same problems.